# Cryptomatte from volumetric environment is not fully opaque

Tags: volumetrics, cryptomatte

World shader is simple *Volume Scatter* with 0.01 density. When I get matte of default cube I get partially transparent result.

Look at red-highlighted values. This is a point near center of the cube's matte:

[image]

Right now I'm multiplying matte to get full alpha, but this slightly corrupts edge antialising...